# DIBS payment gateway callbackURL is very fast

Tags: dibs

I have integrated the DIBS payment gateway in my PHP code.

To protect against the unwanted closing of the browser, I thought of using `callbackUrl`.
But I realised the call to `callbackUrl` is happening even before the normal browser returns to the website. So in that way, I have to check whether a `callbackUrl` is already done or not. But still the SQL data updated by `callbackURL` is not refreshed.

So I was thinking that if DIBS can delay the `callbackURL` at least by few minutes, that would solve my problem. Is there any parameter or technique to do so?

Comment: "To protect against unwanted close of browser..." - unwanted by whom? Maybe the user wants to cancel the transaction ;)

Comment: you want delay about few minutes? there is no such a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any parameters or techniques for this that I know of.
The best practice is to use `acceptReturnUrl` for a visual response to the end-user (if they don't close the browser) and the `callbackUrl` for all your database updating.

I would not recommend trusting `acceptReturnUrl` as this relies on the end-user.

Source: tech.dibspayment.com